# No voltage to 2010 Toyota 4Runner trailer electric brakes

Tags: toyota, brakes, towing, trailer, 4runner

When I step on the brakes in my 2010 Toyota 4Runner, I do not get any DC voltage to the "electric brakes" pin of the 7-pin trailer socket (factory installed). (I measure this by touching the probes on my multimeter to the "electric brakes" pin and the "neutral/-" pin at the same time while the brake pedal is fully depressed.)

Every other trailer socket pin produces voltage as expected (i.e. 12V/+, running lights, left light, right light; admittedly I did not test reverse lights). Note that the brake *lights* do work, but of course that's just the left and right lights powered at the same time.

I pulled and checked *every* fuse under the hood and in the driver foot well, triple-checking any associated with "towing" or "trailer". I also confirmed that both relays associated with "towing" or "trailer" are functioning correctly; not only do they click, but they have minimal resistance (0.2 Ohms) when powered.

Note that I do *not* have any trailer brake controller installed. (I know there's a factory-installed connector for it in the driver foot well; there's nothing connected there.)

I've heard there might be a towing relay behind the panel on the driver's side of the trunk. Should I pull that panel next?

What's the next troubleshooting step I should perform?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get any power out of it without a brake controller installed.

Comment: Most newer factory brake controllers are smart and will not put any voltage to the brake wire unless a trailer is connected that has trailer brakes. There has to be a brake controller before there is any voltage on the brake wire.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks. I’ll install a brake controller and re-test!

Comment: @Moab Thanks! I’ll install a brake controller and re-test!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Moab @Paulster2 The solution is to install a brake controller as indicated in the comments on my question. Thanks!